# Subspace topology and open singletons

Tags: general-topology

$(X, T)$ is an infinite topological space, and $C:= ${{$x$}:{$x$}$∈T$}. $C$ is finite. Does $Y:=X\setminus C$ have any open singleton if we consider the subspace topology on $Y$?

What if X is Hausdorff?

Comment: Do you know what is a subspace topology?

Comment: {B$\bigcap$Y:B$\in$T}

Comment: What if B is open in X, B consisting of some x$\in$ C and a y $\notin$ C?

Comment: It can have. Concider $X=\{1/n:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: And what is the topology here?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that $C$ can be infinite. If it is finite, then you just removed an open and closed set $C$ and $Y\subseteq X$ is open. A set is open in $Y$ iff it is open in $X$ (and contained in $Y$). So there are no more singletons remaining.

Comment: I see, but I actually made a mistake, what I do want to put there is C is finite. However, I think I could find an answer by fixing your example a little bit.. Sorry I made the confusion.

Comment: Yes, exactly, thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think that question makes sense as written. Clearly $C$ is not a subset of $X$. (It is a subset of $P(X)$.)

Comment: I think the OP probably meant $C=\{x\in X\mid \{x\}\in T\}$.

Comment: @PeterFranek you do assume then that the space is $T_1$.

Comment: @Hemno Brandsma: yes, good point! The counterexample is $X=\{x,y\}$ and $T=\{\emptyset, \{x\}, \{x,y\}\}$.

Comment: @PeterFranek I have an infinite version in my answer, as the OP asked for an infinite space..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can, in general.

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{N}$ with the lower topology: all sets $L_k = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: n \le k \}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, plus the emptyset and $X$. Then $0$ is the only isolated point, but in $X \setminus \{0\}$ we have a new isolated point $1$, (it's homeomorphic to $X$ again!).

If $X$ is $T_1$ (so Hausdorff will also do), then finite sets are closed and then $X \setminus C$ is then a (closed-and-)open subset of $X$, so any isolated point of $X \setminus C$ would also have been one of $X$ (as "open in open is open"), which cannot be.

So for $X$ $T_1$ the assertion holds, for mere $T_0$ spaces like the lower topology, this need not hold.